# Cannot access parent page in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, parent, shadowbox

I have this function in a child page (iframe - shadowbox):

```
function returnToParent()  
{
        parent.document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = document.getElementById('nameinput').value;
        self.parent.Shadowbox.close();  
}
```

It sends the value of the text input "Name" to a div in the main page, where it displays a message "Hello, ".
It works fine in Firefox. But it does not work in Google Chrome. It does not send the value, nor does it close the shadowbox.
Is there an alternative of accessing the parent page for google chrome?

Thanks in advance,
Alexander.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably wrong here - however I believe that since it's an IFrame, the 'parent' is actually the same window.  You'd have to get that information and have the page refresh without the iframe and display the information you gathered.

I hope this helps give some different ideas.

Comment: nope, it is not. if we remove the "parent" it also stops working in firefox.